# RestTemplate exchange call gives 503 error when running in Docker container at Kubernetes environment

Tags: docker, spring-boot, kubernetes, resttemplate

My Spring Boot application runs fine when I run on the server as traditional way. 
But, when I create a Docker image with this app and run the container at Kubernetes environment, I get "503 Service Unavailable" error back when the app makes RestTemplate call.

Here is the code snipped where the call is made:

```
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

...

private boolean isActiveUserExist(String userId, String password) {

    String restUrl = "http://10.3.0.176:8888/persons/application_id";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic "+ Utils.base64Creds(userId, password));
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    //construct the URL with Request Parameters parameters    
    try {
      restUrl = restUrl + "?userId=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(userId, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
      throw e;
    }
    restUrl = restUrl + "&applicationPk=1"; //primarykey for this app

    log.debug("Rest URL to check user <{}>.", restUrl);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Person> response = null;

    try{

      response = restTemplate.exchange(restUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, 
          new ParameterizedTypeReference<Person>() {
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Rest URL to check user returns error {}.", e.getMessage());
      throw e;
    }

    Person person = response.getBody();
    log.debug("isActiveUserExist({}) returns: {}",userId,person);

    return  ( person != null ) ;
}    
...
```

Do you see any reason why RestTemplate.exchange call would not work and return 503 when it runs in the Docker Container at Kubernetes?

Comment: This is probably not your code, but the private IP address you use not being available from your container.  How are you running kubernetes from a networking standpoint?

Comment: if you use `kubectl exec` to run a curl command from inside the container, does it work?  Did the two servers both used to be installed on the same server?  Is the target server allowing external requests (listen 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost)? Did you expose the port in your deployment?